# how to fill a complete column with arrayformula and containing Vlookup of base on a single cell criterion

Tags: arrays, import, match, vlookup, array-formulas

I need this exact formula into V1:V column

```
=VLOOKUP('Target Sheet'!$G$1,IMPORTRANGE("MYLIST","FileLInktoAgent!$A$2:$C$45"),2,0)
```

That formula works perfectly for 1 row, I want all the row to have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP('Target Sheet'!G1:G, 
 IMPORTRANGE("MYLIST", "FileLInktoAgent!A2:C45"), 2, 0)))
```